# Editing a dataframe when multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

Hello I am working on a task and want to speed up the speed of my program and that's why I decided to use multiprocessing to achieve the task. Basically I want to read a dataframe, go through each row, check for specific things related to its values and override some of them if necessary. It works fine on a single process, but when I start using multiprocessing I don't override the elements of the dataframe

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import pandas as pd
import requests


def f(d, start, end):
    data = d.df
    for index in range(start, end):
        print(index)
        data.loc[index, 'checked'] = 'yes'
        data.loc[index, 'phone'] = 'phone'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    d = pd.read_excel(r"final.xlsx")
    d['phone'] = 'none'
    d['checked'] = 'no'
    mgr = Manager()
    data = mgr.Namespace()
    data.df = d


    process_pool = []
    start = 0
    end = 10
    for i in range(30):
        print(i)
        p = Process(target=f, args=(data, start, end))
        p.start()
        process_pool.append(p)
        start = end
        end = end + 10

    for p in process_pool:
        p.join()  
    data = d

    print(data)
```

Comment: You could provide to each process part of the complete data frame to check, have it return the checked partial dataframe; and finally, aggregate together the partial dataframe to recreate the original shape.

Comment: Why do you think that multi-processing will speed up anything? If you have multiple processors available, you will indeed have more available processing time. But... you will have to sync all that, and sharing data across multiple processes in Python is not specially simple. Not on a programmer point of view, the multiprocessing module can present it nicely, but on a system one because each process has its own copy of data. Furthermore, iterating over a dataframe at the Python level has terrible performances, while numpy code (used by Pandas) is highly optimized...

Comment: Long story made short, if you want to speed up processing of a dataframe, do no go the multiprocessing (nor multithreading) path, but use the *vectorized* methods of pandas and numpy.

Comment: Well I need to send requests to an API in order to validate the data so using vectorized methods cannot help me.